# Notice Period at a Small Business

Tags: hiring-process, software-industry, united-kingdom

At my current employer I do not have a written contract. This includes not knowing how much notice period I am required to give.

My problem is that prospective employers are asking for my notice period during interviews.

Is there anyway I could ask my current employer without giving away the fact I am job searching?
Alternatively, is there any other way I could attempt to deal with the issue?

Comment: Not a lawyer and YMMV but in my part of the world, when you have no contract it basically means there is no official notice period and you are free to leave with what I call a "conscience" notice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the UK, the minimum notice you are allowed to give is one week.

From this [business link](http://www.businesslink.gov.uk/bdotg/action/detail?itemId=1073792628&type=RESOURCES) article:

> #### Contractual and statutory notice periods
>
> An employee who has worked for a company **continuously** for one month or more must give and receive notice of dismissal/redundancy or intention to leave. The notice period must be included in a written statement of employment particulars which must be issued to your employee within two months of them starting work.

...

> The **minimum** statutory notice period which must be given by an **employee** is at least one week's notice if employed continuously for one month or more by that employer. This minimum is unaffected by longer service.
>
> Minimum notice does not apply to the following people:
>
> - independent contractors or freelance agents - see our guide on employment status
> - employees whose fixed-term contracts have come to an end, with a few exceptions

Note that since you have no formal contract and thus presumably haven't been given your *written statement of employment particulars* then you are perfectly at liberty to require one of your current employer, if you have been there more than a couple of months.

This doesn't necessarily have to give away the fact that you are job hunting. You could approach HR and say *"Hi, I've just been catching up on paperwork at home and realised that I never received my copy of my contract or employment particulars. Could you get them to me as I should have got them within two months of starting"*.

If they refuse or delay your request, then you can remind them that it is a legal obligation on both of you, and that you would really feel more comfortable if your working relationship were on a solid legal footing.

Comment: +1 for the slightly disingenuous approach to HR - you could also say you have been asked to produce a contract for a loan or mortgage application for example...

Comment: And Custom and practice might be relevent if for example the majority of the recent leavers gave 1 months notice  - then that would be seen as "resonable"

Also is there a company hand book? as this may state the notice periods

Comment: @DavidM - Just in case you are being serious, I don't think recommending that people lie is very professional, no matter how small the lie.

Comment: @Neuro - Custom and practice is to obey the law and provide a *written statement of employment particulars*, since they have failed to do that any they have ethically as well as legally given up any right to anything more than the statutory notice period. As to the Employee Handbook, the only reason it has any force at all is because it is referenced in the contract or *wsoep*. *8')

Comment: @MarkBooth well if it went to an IT I bet Custom and practice might override statutiry minimima's

Comment: @Neuro - What do you mean by "if it went to an IT"? If you meant an [Employment Tribunal](http://www.justice.gov.uk/tribunals/employment) then any company seeking compensation for not being given sufficient notice would probably have their case thrown out as soon as it was revealed that they hadn't obeyed the law and provided *a written statement of employment particulars*!

Answer (score 10):

> Is there anyway I could ask my current employer without giving away the fact I am job searching?

Not really.

> Alternatively, is there any other way I could attempt to deal with the issue?

Investigate the standard business practices of your region. At least in the US, 2 weeks is the standard notice time. Otherwise, companies understand that the notice time is actually kind of negotiable (where not otherwise limited legally). When you say you're going to leave, your current company may ask for you to stick around for some extra time to transfer knowledge. Then it's up to you to work with them.

For example, I just changed jobs recently and my new company asked, and I told them "I have a bit of knowledge so it might take a little bit more than 2 weeks." They said 'Sure. We'd love to have you here as soon as possible, but understand that you need to maintain those professional relationships.'

When I put in my resignation, my old company asked for 4 weeks, I said I could give them 3 so I was there for 3 weeks.

Comment: I have to vote this answer based on the fact you point both time period you are required ( by a contract ), what the typical standard time period is, and working with your current employeer in order to maintain professional relationships. Any company you are moving to that does not understand that dynamic and very important task, is a company you should avoid, because they clearly have no problem burning bridges.  Those very same people who burn bridges might be working at the next Google, Apple, or Microsoft and you might be in a leadership position to return the favor.

Comment: How is an answer quoting US custom and practice apropraite for a UK employer

Comment: @neuro Where did Sam indicate that they are in the UK? Not in the question...

Comment: The Q is tagged with  United Kingdom

Comment: @neuro ah, I see now. It was added after I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone hiring you would have some concern if you indicated you would leave your existing position with too short of notice. What is considered "normal" is specific to where you live. In the US, 2 weeks is typical.

You can ask the interviewer for an acceptable range of time.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to see this at work on the www.xperthr.co.uk site (I work for RBI)

The Employment Rights Act 1996, section 86 provides that the statutory minimum notice to be given by **an employee** who has been continuously employed for one month or more to terminate his or her contract is not less than **one week**.

Where the employee has been employed for one month but less than two years, the statutory minimum to be provided **by the employer** is **one week**'s notice. After two years' service this rises to one week for each year of continuous service, although a maximum of 12 weeks' notice applies where the employee has been employed for 12 years or more.

Comment: Why do you jump straight from talking about employee obligations (which is what the question is about) to talking about employer obligations (which are not relevant), as the latter confuses the issue. Hopefully my edit clarifies this.